# How do I install Cinnamon on Xubuntu?

Tags: cinnamon, xubuntu

I have Xubuntu 13.10 on a Lenovo R60 Thinkpad type 9459-AT8, Intel Graphics 945GM, 3GB RAM usable.

I tried to add Cinnamon from Synaptic, but after doing so and cycling power, there's no option to select it at login time. I also tried adding Cinnamon as per http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/ubuntu-cinnamon.html, which did not give me a chance to select Cinnamon after a reboot:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cinnamon
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must log out and when you are at logging screen choose Cinnamon:

[image]